# Errors in Here maps. How they can be fixed?

Tags: here-api

Do you know any possibility to fix a wrong route indicator (properties) by yourself? 
It takes long time to have an error on map corrected by Here support.

For example, we get a wrong route from Berttyoujfalu (Hungary) - to Oradea (Romania)

See attached pictures The problem is a wrong indicator, please see detailed pictures. enter image description here[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xISi4.png)

The routine we used to generate the route is

https://tce.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json?mode=fastest;truck;traffic:disabled&avoidseasonalclosures=true&cost_optimize=1&metricsystem=metric&truckRestrictionPenalty=soft&driver_cost=18&vehicle_cost=0.85&currency=EUR&vehicletype=diesel,24&truckType=tractorTruck&trailersCount=1&limitedWeight=40.0t&weightPerAxle=10.0t&height=4.0m&width=2.50m&length=16.5m&tollVehicleType=3&hybrid=0&emissionType=6&passengersCount=1&commercial=1&trailerType=2&vehicleNumberAxles=2&vehicleWeight=12.0t&heightAbove1stAxle=3.5m&trailerHeight=4.0m&trailerNumberAxles=3&tiresCount=12&maneuverAttributes=none&combineChange=true&routeAttributes=none,no,wp,lg,sc&legAttributes=none,li,sh&linkAttributes=none,fl,le,tr&detail=1&alternatives=1&rollup=none,total,country&jsonattributes=41&waypoint0=geo!stopOver!47.21984,21.54364;;0,0,2,8,9,10,YmVyZXR0eW91amZhbHU=&waypoint1=geo!stopOver!47.05185,21.93873;;0,0,2,8,9,10,b3JhZGVh&app_id=XXX&app_code=XXX&ignorePreferredRoutes=true

This error is very bad, because this route is used by all Here users from Romania.

Answer (score 0):

Please connect for map correction at following ways :

1) Map creator (locate the poi and make the change, Here team will review and approve it)
2) Use Map Feedback API : https://developer.here.com/documentation/map-feedback/dev_guide/topics/quick-start-submit-feedback.html

Can you please confirm if you getting the similar response with routing and fleet API.

Comment: We are checked the above problem on Map Creator. The road attributes for this setion is correct, but in Here Maps yet it appears, and cannot generate the truck route on this road. You can see the screenshot [link](https://ibb.co/MShHg1M)